# (Windows 8.1) Use "Hey Google" to enable a request instead of Pressing Enter

Tags: python, google-api, google-assistant-sdk, google-python-api

So I've followed [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-get-google-assistant-on-your-windows-mac-or-linux-machine/) tutorial to setup Google Assistant on my Windows Laptop.

The only problem is that it requires the user to press the Enter key everytime they wanted to send a request.

I'd prefer to have it like on an Android device, where you could use voice control to activate it. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: The sdk should contain a script for that: `googlesamples-assistant-hotword`.

Comment: The hotword sample requires client-side code that is only available on certain Linux devices. OP would need to look at some alternative on Windows.